# iTunes connect submission claims that I use a beta Xcode version which I don't

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit an App To iTunes connect. When I upload it, everyThing is ok, but when I click on the submit button, suddenly it says that I'm using a beta version of Xcode. I don't understand because I freshly downloaded Xcode from App Store (Version 7.1.1 (7B1005)) and I get a weird message saying that I should compile it with Xcode 6, not a beta version:
Here my original message:

> Chaîne de compilation non valide. Les nouvelles apps et mises à jour
>   d’apps doivent être conçues avec les versions publiques de Xcode 6 et
>   SDK iOS 8 ou versions ultérieures. Ne soumettez pas d’apps conçues
>   avec des logiciels en version bêta.

Translated in english it says:

> Invalidate chains compilation. New apps
>   must be made with public version of Xcode 6 and SDK iOS 8 or later
>   version. Don't submit apps with beta version.

What can I do? My build app version says it has been compiled with SDK build 13B137.

How can I make it works? It seems like a bug to me as it seems so counter intuitive.

Comment: Which SDK do you target?

Comment: Do you still obtain another copy of Xcode 6 or 7? If so, try submitting the app using these. If not, go ahead and download an older version and retry.

Comment: @Bigood I'm building with iOS SDK Target 9.1

Comment: @Linus G I'm downloading Xcode 6.4 since this is what Itunes Connect expect me to do. I'm waiting now that the upload is done to submit it again. But I can stop thinking this is a weird behavior.

Comment: Ok, now I have uploaded a version with Xcode 6.4 targeting SDK iOS 8.4 and I still have the exact error. -_-

Comment: Weird. Definitely report the bug to Apple. And maybe ask the support for help

Comment: Just a wild guess: Please enter this in a terminal `xcode-select -p`. What is the output? If it does not match what you would expect (I get `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`), run `sudo xcode-select -r`. This resets the command line tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is maybe your OS X a beta version?

I had a while back the same problem - I kept deleting and reinstalling Xcode (and related directories) until I somehow realized that I had a beta version of OS X.

itunesconnect will these days reject anything that was either build with beta Xcode or on a beta OS X (even if Xcode is the official release)

I think the error message was never updated for the latest official Xcode version and for the new requirement of none beta Mac OS X version (which is part of the compilation tool chain)

Comment: This is actually clever. Yes I am actually on El Capitan Beta 10.11.2 (15C30). And now it make it completely obvious. Thank you @Uwe, you really helped me on this one!